# Appending repeated images in web page with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, append, clone

I want to use javascript to append some images to a `div` in the web page. Each new instance of the image will be in a loop that includes something like

```
pic=new Image()
pic.src="./images/xyz.jpg"
document.getElementById(div1).appendChild(pic)
```

This works but because there are lots and lots of repeated images chosen randomly, I think that each repeat will be fetching an image from the server that I already have and I wonder how to avoid this overhead.

There are various techniques on the web for cloning object so you might think that something along the lines of

```
appendChild(pic1)
pic2=clone(pic1)
appendChild(pic2)
```

would do the trick but it seems that the cloning includes the `.src` so there would be no saving.  In any case, only one image appears!

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can we see an example online?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if the picture has been downloaded once, the browser will not download another copy. So you can add as many of the same image as you like.

Comment: +1 As long as the URLs are the same, the browser will use its cache.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla - actually not the "cache" since the cache is usually referred to when you are revisiting a page you've been to before. In this case, the image is simply already in-memory.

Comment: Thanks @Nalum and @arnorhs but I'm not entirely convinced - http://annelewington.co.uk/index9.htm shows what I was experimenting with (this is just a dummy page for customer comments so please don't worry about any details other than the script).  http://annelewington.co.uk/index9fast.htm has the same volume of script but only adds text.  The speed difference is very noticeable. I had hoped the browser would cache the pictures but I think that because javascript treats each item as a new image object, it does indeed go back to the server each time.

Comment: I agree with @SteveKimpton and I think that yes, the browser will do new requests, it's only up to the server whether it responds 304 Not Modified or sends the whole file again.

Answer (score 1):

When reloading the two pages, I don't notice any difference in the rendering time (with Google Chome).

My guess is that you're using a browser with a slow JavaScript engine and/or DOM implementation. Also `appendChild()` can be slow. Create the innerHTML as a large String and assign it in one go. Alternatively, use CSS to display the images (using `background-image` and a fixed size) and just create empty DIVs. That should be faster than creating hundreds of image objects.

If you need it even faster, try [CSS sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

Comment: OK, thanks - I'll take up your suggestion of a single string.  You're right, in Chrome there's hardly any difference. In FF3.6, it's significant.

Comment: +1 for using CSS background image as this is probably the only way to avoid downloading the file multiple times.

A little question @AaronDigulla - example:
1) I have downloaded an image, ie. new Image ("load" event litener). Server HTTP response header is saying: hey browser, cache that.
2) I want another instance of Image object (without using canvas toDataUrl etc.).

Will this result in new server request? I think it will and server will respond 304 Not Modified OR will send the file again. Is that correct? (than the answer from arnorhs is incorrect)